# Microphone input iOS mediastreamtrack (Web App)

Tags: javascript, ios, microphone, p5.js, mediastreamsource

I am working on a project that requires a mic input from a mobile phone. I am using the p5.js sound library and everything is working fine on Android (Chrome). Unfortunately I get the message "mediastreamtrack not supported" when I open the website in iOS (both Safari and Chrome).

After some searching, it seems like it is just not supported by Safari or iOS in general? 
I wasn't able to find an solution so far. Is there a way to fix this, a way to work around it? I am using getLevel(), fft.analyze(), and fft getEnergy(). But it would be enough to just get the Level.

Basically, I just want to find out if there is an input above a certain level. 
I want to avoid creating an App for it and have the function implemented in a website.

Thank you!